# Strange bug in a Cypher Neo4J request

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Why when I make a request below:

```
PROFILE MATCH (c1:Concept)-[:AT]->(ctx:Context{uid:'60156a60-d3e1-11ea-9477-f71401ca7fdb'}) 
WITH DISTINCT c1 RETURN c1;
```

It takes less than a second, but when I add another condition to it like

```
PROFILE MATCH (c1:Concept)-[:AT]->(ctx:Context{uid:'60156a60-d3e1-11ea-9477-f71401ca7fdb'}) 
WITH DISTINCT c1 
MATCH (c2:Concept)-[:AT]->(ctx:Context{uid:'60156a60-d3e1-11ea-9477-f71401ca7fdb'}) 
RETURN c1;
```

Which is the same, it stalls my Neo4J database?

I use 3.3.9.

Answer (score 0):

The exported PROFILE plan image should show the problem, but I can guess at it.

It's important to remember that with Cypher, operations execute per row. And at the start, you only have one row.

So the first part of the query here:

```
MATCH (c1:Concept)-[:AT]->(ctx:Context{uid:'60156a60-d3e1-11ea-9477-f71401ca7fdb'}) 
WITH DISTINCT c1
```

This executes once, and now you have one row per distinct `c1` node. Let's say, for the sake of example, that you have 1000 rows as a result at this point in the query. Now for the remainder of the query:

```
...
MATCH (c2:Concept)-[:AT]->(ctx:Context{uid:'60156a60-d3e1-11ea-9477-f71401ca7fdb'}) 
RETURN c1;
```

The MATCH here (which will likely consist of either an index lookup or label scan+filter, then expansion, then label filtering) executes **per input row**. So if you had 1000 rows half-way through, now you're performing this entire MATCH sequence for each of those rows, so that happens 1000 times. Your rows are multiplying out the operational work that needs to be done, and execution time will multiply out too.

You should see proof of that in the number of rows flowing in your PROFILE plan. Watch how the rows of c1 feed into the next NodeIndex Seek (or NodeByLabelScan and Filter) operation, and how that continues until the end of the query.

Comment: Ok, thank you! So what would be an efficient way to get the nodes of the type `Concept` linked to the specified `Context` node and to find the connections between them without having to reiterate over and over again?

Comment: If you're using the Neo4j Browser, returning the nodes will show the relationships between them by default. If you need these returned in the query, collect the results of the :Concept nodes linked to the specified :Context node, then use `CALL apoc.algo.cover()` to find all the relationships between them. You'll need APOC installed for this. You can use `CALL apoc.help("cover")` to get more info about the APOC function or proc containing that text in the name.

Comment: – ok, i'm trying this `MATCH (c1:Concept)-[:AT]->(ctx:Context{uid:'60156a60-d3e1-11ea-9477-f71401ca7fdb'}) 
WITH COLLECT (DISTINCT c1) as cs CALL apoc.algo.cover(cs) YIELD rel RETURN rel;` and also `apoc.algo.cover(c1)` but it's too slow, much slower than querying the relationships directly using the `apoc` function...

Comment: Which APOC apoc function are you using?